# Wait until event occured

Tags: c#, html

I have application that uses webBrower, but when i set URL it doesn't wait until it's loaded, but i want to do something with the website, is there anyway to stop the method without using loops or should i us multi threading?

Comment: I had to do several different things depending on the page loaded and I used variables and load completed events, but that became really confusing

Comment: I have been able to successfully use the DocumentCompleted Event Handler to control when the next piece of code is executed.  Using the DocumentCompleted Event Handler, I then called into other methods that performed the actions that I was aiming for (automatic text insertion into text boxes, clicking buttons, etc.).  Using the documentcompleted event handler ensures that the page is fully loaded before your other code runs.

Answer (score 0):

@Marek Beseda you can use setTimeout() for the same